# Alterar uma entidade passando uma list

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, restful

Olá, eu tenho uma classe professor cadastrada e quero altera-la passando um array de matérias.

tenho o seguinte código:

classe professor:

```
//... atributos não importantes ao problema

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "teacher_x_lesson", 
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_teacher"), 
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_lesson"))
    private List<Lesson> lesson;
```

No resource cheguei até aqui porem não sei se estou no caminho certo.

```
@PutMapping("/{id}/lesson")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_PUT_TEACHER') and #oauth2.hasScope('wride')")
    public void putLessonTeacher(@PathVariable Long id, List<Lesson> idLesson) {

        Teacher teacher = repository.findById(id).get();

        teacher.setLesson(idLesson);

        BeanUtils.copyProperties(idLesson, teacher, "id" );

    }
```

No Postman estou passando o seguinte:

```
{
    "lesson": [
        {"id":1}    
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Opa Cleriston,

Não sei bem se é isto que você quer.

Mas agora você tem que:

- consultar as matérias que estão cadastradas no BD , criar o array, passá-lo para seu objeto professor, e persistir usando o `repository.save(teacher).`

Comment: Olá Leonardo, digamos que tenho a classe professor cadastrada no banco. Contudo o atributo list matérias mudam constantemente. Não estou conseguindo fazer esta alteração, enviando por exemplo 3 materias ao mesmo tempo via post

Answer (score 0):

Tente algo como:

```
teacher.getLessons().addAll(asList(lesson1, lesson2, lesson3));
//getLessons() = List<Lessons> da classe Teacher
repositoryTeacher.saveAll();
```

Recomendo você criar um DTO para manipular as entradas e saídas com informações que realmente são necessárias e desacoplar sua camada de domain do controller.
Tenho aqui um repository que pode te ajudar:

https://github.com/diegobiazin/spring-boot-ionic-backend/blob/master/src/main/java/com/diegobiazin/cursomc/resources/CategoriaResource.java